# Scan a string including spaces in C

Tags: c, whitespace, scanf

In my code:

```
scanf("%s", &text);
printf("%s\n", text);
```

Input:

```
hi how are you
```

Output:

```
hi
```

and not

```
hi how are you
```

what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [fgets](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fgets/)

> The fgets() function reads at most one
>   less than the number of characters
>   specified by n from the given stream
>   and stores them in the string
>   s.Reading stops when a newline
>   character is found, at end-of-file or
>   error. The newline, if any, is
>   retained.  If any characters are read
>   and there is no error, a `\0'
>   character is appended to end the
>   string.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're looking for

```
ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);
```

Which will read up to a newline delimiter. Or if you're using some other delimiter

```
ssize_t getdelim(char **lineptr, size_t *n, int delim, FILE *stream);
```

Comment: Only on linux or other system using GNU libc "Both getline() and getdelim() are GNU extensions. They are available since libc 4.6.27. " (http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline)

Comment: @Paul; Used to be a GNU extension yes, it's nowadays part of POSIX.1-2008.

Comment: thanks. I need to read up on that - how widely implemented is it?

Answer (score 1):

Use [fgets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fgets) to get your input:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    char text[80];
    fgets(text, sizeof(text), stdin);
    printf("%s\n", text);
}
```