# Why can't I get the length of the whole string?

Tags: c, string, strlen

I tried strlen(string). And I tried writing the code for finding the length of the whole string. However it still tends to stop counting the length when the first 'space' is reached. Why does  it happen? What is the solution? I'm trying to stop at '\0'. Shouldn't this work? Here is the part of the code.

```
int main(void) {
char phrase[256];
char phrase2[256];
int i,j,size;
scanf("%255s", phrase);
for(i=0;phrase[i]!='\0';i++){
    size++;
}
...
```

Comment: note: your `size` var is redundant, because `i` would already be the length of the string when the loop terminates.

Comment: Marc, the problem is that i is not a length. I mean, if I printf the i after this loop. If i scanf the following input: "asd dsa". And then printf("%i", i). It shows me 3, and not 6.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scan a string including spaces in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269765/scan-a-string-including-spaces-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it stops counting is because scanf reads one word at a time. It's reading the first word and then halting, ignoring the rest of the line.

Instead, use [fgets](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/):

> Reads characters from stream and stores them as a C string into str
>   until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the
>   end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

You can read from standard input like so:

```
fgets(phrase, 256, stdin);
```

Have you considered using [strlen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/) to measure the length of your input?

Finally, you should get into the habit of initialising variables when you declare them:

```
int i = 0,j = 0, size = 0;
```

When a variable is declared its value is 'whatever was in memory', until you set its value. In your example 'length' is never initialised, which will lead to unexpected behaviour. Initialising variables is a good way to avoid unexpected behaviour and time wasted tracking down bugs.

Comment: thanks! I will try fgets. As I said, strlen also stops at the 'space'. Though, I think it should not be so. May be the problem is with my eclipse?

Comment: @user3349993 strlen is working correctly. What's happening is that you're only storing the first word of input in 'phrase', and then it's measuring the length of the word. Replace scanf with fgets and use strlen. That should produce the correct behavior :).

Answer (score 1):

> However it still tends to stop counting the length when the first 'space' is reached.

Well, that is the default behaviour of `scanf`. You can use `fgets` to fix your problem. Also, to add a note `size` is not *initialized*

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanf() function
```

does not take spaces.
whenever space is occured, it considers it as end of input and puts '\0' at that position.

you can do one thing:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s",phrase);
```

this scanf will take input till newline is occured i.e. you press the enter :)

Secondly important thing in your code is, you have not initialized size to 0.

Here is the solution:

```
int main(void) 
{
    char phrase[256];
    char phrase2[256];
    int i,j,size=0;    //initialize size
    scanf("%[^\n]s",phrase);   //input taken till '\n'
    for(i=0;phrase[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        size++;
    }
}
```

Comment: nice. Really helped, thanks! I guess, I had problem with scanning the whole input into "phrase", because now even strlen works.

Answer (score 0):

`sscanf` stops at the first white space character. Here's a snippet from `man scanf` about the field width specifier.

> An optional decimal integer which specifies the maximum field width. Reading of characters stops either when this maximum is reached or when a nonmatching character is found, whichever happens first.

If you would like to read the entire line, use `fgets`

```
fgets(phrase, 255, stdin);
```

Answer (score 0):

%s consumes words (separated by one or more spaces),
You could use %c which consumes characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char phrase[256];
  int size;
  scanf("%255c", phrase);
  size = strlen(phrase) - 1; /* -1 is for EOL */
  printf("length is %d\n", size);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The `scanf()` function can only read one word at a time. You can change the code to

```
scanf("%255[\n]s",phrase);
```

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{   
char phrase[256];
int i,size;
scanf("%255[^\n]s", phrase);
for(i=0;phrase[i]!='\0';i++)
{
if(phrase[i]!=' ')
    size++;
}
printf("%d",size);
}