# How to get word by word as input without getting as an entire string in C?

Tags: c, algorithm

Suppose I have a paragraph as input like this

> C is an imperative procedural language. It was designed to be compiled
>   using a relatively straightforward compiler, to provide low-level
>   access to memory, to provide language constructs that map efficiently
>   to machine instructions, and to require minimal run-time support.
>   Despite its low-level capabilities, the language was designed to
>   encourage cross-platform programming

How to get word by word as input without getting as an entire paragraph?

Comment: `scanf` with `%s`?

Comment: I rather consider `fscanf()`

Comment: What kind of input? File? Prompt?

Comment: prompt not file

Comment: Write the code and we will help you if you get stuck.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22433309/why-cant-i-get-the-length-of-the-whole-string/22433348#22433348 That question says they get things a word at  atime but wnat the whole thing - so the code taht doesn't work for them might near enough work for you

Comment: `strtok` works . . . http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user hits enter, the input stream holds the entire block of input along with the carriage return. From there it's just a matter of reading or formatting it to your liking.

In your case, strtok could work fine so long as you don't care about the punctuation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

    char Stream[1024] = {0};
    char* TokenPointer = 0;
    const char Token[] = " ";

    fgets(Stream,sizeof(Stream),stdin);
    TokenPointer = strtok(Stream, Token);
    while(TokenPointer != 0)
    {
        puts(TokenPointer);
        TokenPointer = strtok(0,Token);
    }
    return 0;
}
```